# Css Transition is working only one time

Tags: html, css

I have created a transition effect, when i click location icon a select box appears and it pushes the location icon to the left. But problem is it's working only in firefox but in chrome its working only one time. I dont know why is this happening. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Here is my HTML CODE

```
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-right pad-top">
  <a href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true" id="capture_image_01"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true" id="location-show-hoide-point"></i>
  </a>

  <span id="post-location-conainer" style="display:none">
  <select>
  <option value="No Value Selected">Select Target City</option>
  <option value="City 1">City 1</option>
  <option value="City 2">City 2</option>
  </select>
  </span>

  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs close-button" type="button" value="Post" id="btnPost" />
  </div>
```

Here is my css

```
#post-location-conainer select{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#post-location-conainer select.open{
  width: 150px;
}
```

Here is the JS

```
    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#location-show-hoide-point',function (){
        $('#post-location-conainer select').toggleClass('open');
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to slightly change your code as:

### Code Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#location-show-hoide-point').on('click', function() {
    $('span').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.dib-elements a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.open {
  width: 135px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-right pad-top dib-elements">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true" id="capture_image_01"></i>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true" id="location-show-hoide-point"></i>
  </a>
  <span>
  <select id="post-location-conainer">
  <option value="No Value Selected">Select Target City</option>
  <option value="City 1">City 1</option>
  <option value="City 2">City 2</option>
  </select></span>

  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-xs close-button" type="button" value="Post" id="btnPost" />
</div>
```

> There is no need to use `$(document).on('click','#location-show-hoide-point',function (){...` as it is being used to delicately handle the `jQuery` events or better to say when elements are not present when DOM loads.
>
> There is no need to use `<span id="post-location-conainer" style="display:none">` i.e. inline styling when you are using `toggleClass` just to manipulate the `width`.
>
> And always keep in mind to define `inline` DOM to `inline-block` or `block` when using them for spaces, divisioning, element wrapper.